# How would you translate 「腰掛で仕事をする」?

Tags: meaning, translation

How would you translate 「腰掛{こしかけ}で仕事{しごと}をする」in this sentence.

> 男が奢{おご}るのは当{あ}たり前{まえ}で、まだ女子{じょし}は腰掛で仕事をする人も多く、24歳{さい}25歳が結婚{けっこん}のリミット？！

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 「腰掛で仕事をする」

「腰掛{こしかけ}で」 in this phrase has an idiomatic meaning of "***temporarily***" even though the original meaning of 「腰掛」is "a chair", "a bench", etc.

Thus, the phrase in question means "**(many women) still just work temporarily (until they get married)**."  Hence, they tend to make less money than their male colleagues because those women workers are assigned simpler tasks, which is why the male workers often end up 奢る-ing them. 「奢る」 means "to treat others" or "to pay for others".

FYI: This might surprise some, but 「椅子{いす}」 is a Sino-loanword while 「腰掛」 is an originally Japanese word.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think 腰掛【こしかけ】 also includes a meaning like "the act of sitting".  When I first parsed this question, that's the sense I had in mind: 腰掛で as roughly equivalent to 腰を掛けて, with the image in my head being one of somebody sitting down _temporarily_ to get something done.

Comment: 腰掛{こしか}ける is certainly an existing verb meaning "to sit down".  To mean "to work sitting down", we usually say 座って仕事（を）する.  Still, this provides plenty of punning opportunities which I originally thought of mentioning but decided against  fearing it might confuse some users.  For instance, 「腰掛でテーブルを作ってます。」 can mean two entirely different things -- 1) "I am making tables out of chairs. " and 2) "I am making tables temporarily (until I get a better and possibly permanent job)."  Change it to 腰掛けてテーブルを作ってます。 and it will have a third meaning of "I make tables sitting down."

Comment: Eiríkr, `I think 腰掛 also includes a meaning like "the act of sitting"` ううん… 「腰掛ける」「腰掛け**て** 」とか動詞じゃなくて、「腰掛+ **で** 」みたいな名詞の「腰掛」には、"act of sitting" の意味はないです。[この辞書にも載ってないですし](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%85%B0%E6%8E%9B/#jn-78582)。普通は、「椅子」のことか、「とりあえず就く職業」って意味で使います。明鏡も、`こし‐かけ【腰掛け】〘名〙❶ 腰をおろすための台。いす。❷ 本来望んでいる職や地位につくまでの間、とりあえずある職や地位に身を置くこと。また、その職や地位。`